# Generate large dataset of dates for each user

Tags: sql, database, psql

I'm looking for SQL help generating a large dataset.

I have a list of users (id) and the date they activated with our service (activated_date).

I'm looking to generate a data set that has an entry for every day from the user's activated date to today.

**What I Have Today**

```
--------------------
id | activated_date
--------------------
2  | 01/01/2017
63 | 23/04/2018
.. | ...
--------------------
```

**What I want to achieve**

```
--------------------
id | date
--------------------
2  | 01/01/2017 <-- activation date
2  | 02/01/2017
2  | 03/01/2017
2  | 04/01/2017
2  | 05/01/2017
.. | ...
2  | 27/10/2018 <-- yesterday
63 | 23/04/2018 <-- activation date
63 | 24/04/2018
63 | 25/04/2018
63 | 26/04/2018
.. | ...
63 | 27/10/2018 <-- yesterday
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Can you share what you've tried so far?

Comment: I'm using PSQL here

Comment: If you got a calendar table (which is very useful anyway) you can simply join to it using `calendar_date between activated_date and current_date)`

Comment: @dnoeth that's a good idea!

Comment: @dnoeth the problem should solve using `RECURSIVE CTE`. Why do create a new table?

Comment: @JamesPatrick create a new table is not a good idea. because you add an extra object that you need it only for one reason in a query.

Comment: @MohammadMohabbati: A calendar table is one of the basic things in a Data Warehouse Enivironment. IMHO it should exist in every database, you can do  lots of things with it.

Comment: @dnoeth it is absolutely correct in Data Warehouse databases, but in OLTP databases it is just a trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the dates recursively so the problem will solve by `RECURSIVE CTE` as follow:

**create test table:**

```
create table your_table
(
  id    int not null,
  activated_date    timestamp  not null
);
```

**add sample data:**

```
insert into your_table
values
(2, '2017/01/01'),
(63, '2018/04/23');
```

**and final the recursive query:**

```
with
recursive
    cte(id, active_date)
as
(
    select
        id,
        activated_date  as active_date
    from
        your_table
    union all
    select
        t.id,
        active_date + justify_days(interval '1 days')
    from
        cte
    inner join
        your_table t
    on
        cte.id = t.id
    where
        cte.active_date < now()
)
select
    *
from
    cte
order by 1, 2;
```

**try it on:** [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=bc4796f85ae786d5148cc2962e6b8544)